# I opened a blender file then the meshes and the vertices sort of spiked or exploded for no reason. Has anyone here encountered the same bug?

Tags: animation, mesh, materials

[image]
I seem cant find any definite question or answer pertaining to this problem. I am using blender 2.83 lts because the latest blender version crashes on my PC.

Comment: Your question lacks necessary information and implies that there is no reason yet you claim its a bug. To get some ideas of how to improve your question so you might finde the Answer start here https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Comment: Doe's this happen with that specific file or with all files?

Comment: All files. I am clueless about what caused it.

Comment: Also the startup file? So your default cube is no cube? / what kinds of files have you tried?

Comment: Just the default .blend file. Like I said, I have no idea what caused it. Im not sure if it was a bug or a hardware problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, update, I solved the problem: Update your graphics card driver that is appropriate for your hardware, otherwise those texture glitches will occur. That can solve the issue. tnx!

Comment: Nice to hear that you found a solution. You can mark your own answer as correct so the question gets closed.